Ubuntu 22.04 with kernel 6.5.0-27-generic crashes exactly once per day
I've been trawling through my log files but I don't really know what to look for to discover what is causing my new PC to crash once per day.
When it happens I cannot reboot using alt+SysRq REISUB, I have to turn it off physically.
The crash usually happens quite soon after boot up. It has occurred a couple of times before I've entered the password to decrypt my SSD.
I find it curious that once rebooted the system remains stable.
I've tried setting:
vm.max_map_count = 218616

but this has not helped.
Nvidia
There were also a lot of complaints about
[drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership

But according to nvidia, this can be ignored.
Can you advise on where to look for clues as to what is causing this?
My graphics card is an Nvidia 4060 RTX. I've tried reinstalling the nvidia 550 driver using:
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-550

This didn't work so I tried manually installing the driver that I downloaded from the Nvidia site:
NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-550.78.run

If I can't find a solution I will have to install Windows because I know that the hardware will run fine on that OS.

You may use journalctl -b0 -p1 to view only the messages of highest priority for the current boot, -b1 would show them for the last boot, so maybe you find the messages for such a boot which leads to a crash. If nothing suspicious is revealed, decreasing the priority to -p2, -p3 might help. Look for the time stamp of such a crash, maybe this helps to isolate the problem.

journalctl -b0 -p2
GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
Gives me:
GLib-CRITICAL: g_hash_table_foreach_remove_or_steal: assertion 'version == hash_table->version' failed
